# ListView won't update

Tags: android, listview, listadapter, ondestroy

When I run my class the list view is populated with one song the first time but since then I have add songs and they won't add to the list view only the first one is there. I think that my activity is not restarting every time it closes. Here is my update method:

```
public void updatelist() {

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        for(int j=0;j<cursor.getCount();j++) {

            int ALBUM_ID =  cursor.getInt((cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ID)));
            int pathcolumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
            String path1 = cursor.getString(pathcolumn);
            String album_url = null;
            Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, ALBUM_ID);
            album_url = uri.toString();
            ContentResolver res = this.getContentResolver();

            // Album
            String album_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM));
            String year = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.YEAR));
            // String year = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.NUMBER_OF_SONGS));

            // artist
            String artist_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.ArtistColumns.ARTIST));

            // display name
            String DisplayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));

            //title
            String Title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE));

            songtitle.add(Title);
            artistname.add(artist_name);
            albumname.add(album_name);
            path.add(path1);
        }
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.song,songtitle);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And here is my destroy method

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
adapter.clear();
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: how about you try clearing the adapter in onPause() instead if you want to refresh the list every time you close the app, since onDestroy()will be called when the OS wants to kill the app, not when the user shuts the app down.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using [`CursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) or [`SimpleCursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html). It can make your life much easier when you're already working with `Cursor`s.